# How can I create a separate window in an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am working on an excel dashboard. I have several sections and would like to create one section with a "window" of data. The data will be pulled from another worksheet from the same workbook. The data is 11 columns long. Is there a way for me to create a separate section for this data? I want the "window" to be a specific size on the dashboard so it will require a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: I've never done this, but I think adding an ActiveX MSForms Frame may give you the basic structure for the window.  You should then be able to use VBA to pull in whatever data you're looking for.

Comment: See [this SO post](http://superuser.com/questions/554507/excel-2010-freeze-column-to-both-horizontal-and-vertical-scroll) for one approach.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Excel "Split" command (on the View tab)? It allows you to break a sheet into separate scrollable sections. After hitting "Split", the position of the split bars can be dragged to a new position. So the idea is that your "data window" is still on the same sheet, but you position the split bars to keep those cells in view, while scrolling thru the rest.

[image]

Comment: Does this work with different spreadsheets? I cannot find that option if so... :(

Comment: @Jerry - The Split command has been in Excel since Excel 2000. What version are you using?

Comment: 2007. I opened a new workbook with 2 sheets: `Sheet1` & `Sheet2` but can't get a view of both sheets through `Split`, which is what I understand the OP is asking for.

Comment: Split will only work on a single worksheet. To view two separate sheets in the same workbook, create a second window with View/New Window. Then, enable concurrent viewing with View/Arrange All. Select the view style you want (horizontal, vertical, etc.), making sure that "Windows of Active Workbook" is checked. After the split view is shown, you can rearrange the two window panes as you want.  See [this SO post](http://superuser.com/questions/554507/excel-2010-freeze-column-to-both-horizontal-and-vertical-scroll) for related info.

Comment: @chuff - using the arrange is also a good solution. But it is possible to use split with multiple sheets by referencing the other sheets in range of the split display sheet. So depending on the user, there are at least these two options.

Comment: Yes, you're right - didn't think of the second option!

Answer (score 0):

try an =offset formula with a scroll bar. ***Example*** =offset(sheet2!a1,aa1,0,11,3)

Sheet2!a1 = your sheet/cell your pulling data from

aa1 = the cell you've assigned your scroll bar to (rows)

0 = columns

11 = height (number of cells tall)

3 = width (number of cells wide)

**scroll bar is in developer options**

Enable Developer options:
https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/developer_tab2013.php

scroll bar help: 
https://trumpexcel.com/create-a-scroll-bar-in-excel/

Comment: I guess that this is answering the easy part of the question — how to display data from one sheet on another — but I find it unclear.   The hard part is how to put that reflection into a separate, scrollable window — what do you have to say about that?  Please post your answer *in* your answer (and add links to supplement that).